# What does allowhighfees in sendrawtransaction actually does?

Tags: transactions, transaction-fees, raw-transaction, sendrawtransaction

lets say.

i have created a raw transaction with `inputs = outputs` aka setting `0 fees`.

so when i do

```
bitcoin-cli sendrawtransaction <signed_hex> 1
```

`1` is for `allowhighfees`

what it actually does ?
if it increases fees ? then how much ?

how much fees does it sets per byte ?

What if there is not much satoshis in input to cover the fees ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fee is whatever you define in the raw transaction, based on the difference between inputs and outputs.  `sendrawtransaction` never changes it.  However, as a safety measure, it will normally reject your transaction if the fee exceeds a certain "absurd" threshold, so that you don't accidentally lose a lot of coins by miscalculating your raw transaction.  If you set the `allowhighfees` parameter, this check is disabled, and you can send a transaction with fees as high as you wish.

The threshold value can be set with the `maxtxfee` command line / config file option.

Comment: so its just precaution measure to not send all btc in fees.

Comment: Indeed, the only effect is possibly not creating a transaction instead of sending a transaction with enormous fee. It doesn't affect the fee of anything that'd be sent anyway.